# Add Fixed button inside scrollview which is visible even when scrolling

Tags: android

[image]I want to make a view( a button actually) which is inside a scrollview , but when the user scolls down and the button is going up, it moves up only till it reaches the top of the visible screen and then stays there like a fixed header until the user scrolls up again and then it returns to its original position.

I have given the screens for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I'm almost sure that Button is not really inside the ScrollView. The ScrollView is probably in a RelativeLayout and the Button must be in the same RelativeLayout with AlignParentTop set to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way I have solved this is by copying the same view outside the scrollview and keeping it hidden. Only to make it visible when the old button is visisble again.

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
        int oldx, int oldy) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    if (mPriceBtn.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        // View is within the visible window

        mPriceHiddenBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        // View is not within the visible window

        //mPriceBtn.setY(y);

        mPriceHiddenBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/). It's about an ActionBar with similar behavior, made by ome of Google's own Android devs. I'm guessing you can find most of what you need there.