# How to keep Android Button view in the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, view

I have an activity which contains mainly 2 components: A Scroll view and a Button.
I want to place the button at the buttom of the screen, fixed.

I tried many things but i cannot keep the button location fixed at the button of the screen, bacause as the content of the scroll view increases, the button is pushed outside the activity screen.

I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

My XML file is clean (*all custom views are programmatically written, can't be shared!*):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editableViewGroup"></LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Changes"
    android:id="@+id/customButton" />
```

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: Hey @ikis look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912232/add-fixed-button-inside-scrollview-which-is-visible-even-when-scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- ... -->

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Changes"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` to host your views and pin the `Button` to the bottom of the layout.

Comment: Yeah that do works! but it has got one problem. The scroll view fills the space behind the button. How to limit the scroll view height till the height of button?

Comment: Change the `ScrollView` in the layout to align with parent top and be above the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative layout try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use LinearLayout or relativeLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/editableViewGroup"></LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

   <Button
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Save Changes"
      android:id="@+id/customButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```